# Show byte representation of generic type

Tags: beginner, rust

I am new to Rust. I would like to know any better way of doing this and if it can be done preferably with safe code.

```
use std::mem;
use std::mem::size_of;

fn show_byte <T> ( element: T) {

    let array: * mut u8 = unsafe{ mem::transmute(&element) };
    for i in (0.. size_of::<T>()) {
         let current = (array as usize + i) as *mut u8;
         print!("{:X}", unsafe { *current });
    }
}

fn main() {
   show_byte(-1i64);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any safe method in the standard library to do this, so we need some unsafe code.

In your code, you have two `unsafe` blocks. However, the first one is unnecessary: you can use `as` to perform the cast, but you need two consecutive casts, because we can't cast from `&T` to `*mut u8` directly. Actually, you should use `*const u8` here instead, since you don't actually mutate the referent. So, instead of `mem::transmute`, you can write:

```
let array = &element as *const T as *const u8;
```

If you really need a `*mut u8`, then you'd need to define `element` as `mut` and write `&mut element` instead of `&element`.

However, I would do this differently. I'd write a function to turn a `&T` into a slice of bytes (`&[u8]`), which would encapsulate the only `unsafe` operation of the program. Then, we can use a simple `for` loop on that slice to print each byte.

```
use std::mem;
use std::slice;

fn bytes_of<T>(value: &T) -> &[u8] {
    unsafe {
        slice::from_raw_parts(
            value as *const T as *const u8, mem::size_of::<T>())
    }
}

fn show_as_bytes<T>(element: T) {
    for b in bytes_of(&element) {
        print!("{:X}", b);
    }
}

fn main() {
    show_as_bytes(-1i64);
}
```

Note that the `bytes_of` function plays a very important role that would be lost if it was inlined (by hand): the lifetime of the returned byte slice is tied to the lifetime of the input parameter. It's as if it was written thus:

```
fn bytes_of<'a, T>(value: &'a T) -> &'a [u8] {
    // ...
}
```

If the function's body was inlined, the slice returned by `slice::from_raw_parts` would be unconstrained, and the compiler wouldn't be able to report an error if the slice accidentally outlived the data it references, causing subtle memory errors at runtime.

---

*Bonus:* Here's how I would format your original code (note the changes to whitespace and the removal of parentheses).

```
use std::mem::size_of;

fn show_byte<T>(element: T) {
    let array: *mut u8 = unsafe { mem::transmute(&element) };
    for i in 0..mem::size_of::<T>() {
         let current = (array as usize + i) as *mut u8;
         print!("{:X}", unsafe { *current });
    }
}

fn main() {
    show_byte(-1i64);
}
```